# Hardness of quadratic programming (QP) with linear constrains vs. quadratic constrains

Tags: optimization, quadratic, np-hard

[Wikipedia: Quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) says that a positive definite quadratic programming (QP) with linear constraints can be solved in polynomial time: “For positive definite Q, the ellipsoid method solves the problem in polynomial time.[6]”

On the other hand, mixed integer linear program (MILP) can be converted into quadratically constrained quadratic program (QCQP). We know that MILP is NP-hard so QCQD must be NP-Hard in general (again from: [Wikipedia:Quadratically constrained quadratic program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program)).

So does that mean that if you have a quadratic term in your constrains the problem is NP-hard and if it is in objective function and it is positive definite, then it can be solved at polynomial time?

Comment: Convex QPs and QCPs are "easy". Non-convex ones are not.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, My real question is whether it they can be solved in  polynomial time or not. A positive definite QP can be solved in polynomial time. How about positive definite QCPs?

Comment: Convex QCPs are SOCPs which can be solved in polynomial time.